OnAfterRenderAsync Not Triggered in Blazor Web App When Running in Electron After .NET 8.0 Migration
I've recently migrated my Blazor Server app from .NET 6.0 to a Blazor Web App on .NET 8.0. After the migration, I encountered an issue where OnAfterRenderAsync was not being triggered.
To fix this, I modified the <Route /> component in App.razor to:
<Routes @rendermode="RenderMode.InteractiveServer" />

This change resolved the issue when running the app in a standard web environment. However, when I bundle and run the same web app in Electron, OnAfterRenderAsync is not triggered.
Why would OnAfterRenderAsync fail to trigger in Electron after the .NET 8.0 migration, even though it works in the web environment? Are there additional settings or configurations needed to ensure OnAfterRenderAsync works consistently in Electron?
Environment

.NET Version: 8.0
Electron.NET Version: 23.6.2.0
Blazor hosting model: InteractiveServer

Any insights on resolving this would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

this could possibly be a caching issue.  Try forcing electron to reload/refresh.  Also check to be sure the Electron app is calling the same URL.

Did the application throw any exception inside the console after published to the server?

@BrandoZhang I added logs everywhere and tested; no exceptions or method entry logs were recorded.

Could you please give me a minimal sample to reproduce the issue?
